# Sum of the series $S_k$

Tags: sequences-and-series

Suppose $S_k$ be the sum of an infinite geometric series with first term $\frac{k-1}{k!}$ and common ratio $1/k$  for $k = 1,2...$.

What's the value of $\sum_1^\infty S_k $?

I get $S_1 =0$, $S_2= 1$ and $\sum_1^\infty S_k = 1-e$. However the answer options don't have this choice. Am I missing something or is there an error in the question?

Comment: I think you mean $\sum_{k=1}^\infty S_k = e-1$.

Comment: If a geometric sequence starts with zero, then all of its terms are zero.

Comment: @player3236: sorry, yes.

Comment: @gerry myerson: S_k is not a geometric series

Comment: Then why do you write "Suppose $S_k$ be the sum of an infinite geometric series"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have $S_1=0$ and for all $k\geq 2$,
$$S_k = \frac{k-1}{k!} \times \frac{1}{1- \frac{1}{k}} = \frac{1}{(k-1)!}$$

so $$\sum_{k=1}^{+\infty} S_k =\sum_{k=2}^{+\infty} \frac{1}{(k-1)!}  = e-1$$